# Core plot data source returns huge number

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am implementing a scatter graph in core plot and one of the data source methods is returning a huge number. Here is the method:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [self.values count];
}

- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            if (index < [self.practices count]) {
                return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
            }
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:

            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Practices"]) {
                return self.values[index];
            }
            break;
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

Here is the population of self.values:

```
    NSMutableArray *value = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:200];

    for (int i = 200; i > 0; i--) {
        NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 200;
        [value addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomNumber]];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *highestToLowest = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
    [value sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:highestToLowest]];

    self.values = [value copy];
```

The graph is crashing when it calls: `return self.values[index];`. When I try to debug the application I am finding that the index passed in is very large.

Here is a picture of that variable. It's the one called index:

[image]

I am trying to figure out why this number is so large. Everything seems to be similar to other graphs I have implemented. However this seems to be throwing in a large number.

Comment: The code you posted looks fine. Check the rest of your app and make sure the `values` array is always initialized before the graph tries to draw itself for the first time. Try logging the contents of the array in the datasource to see what's in it.

Comment: Hi Eric, the values array is initialised correctly. Inside the datasource it is showing the correct data. However I am still getting this large number.

Comment: I have added NSLog and it prints out the large number for the first time around and then it prints out the correct indexes. So must be a problem with the first loop through data. I create the self.values array in init method which is called before the data source. So puzzling why the first loop has a bad index.

Comment: As the index type is NSUInteger if the index is -1 you might get a huge number printed when formatted using NSUInteger. I know NSTabeView will return -1 as a selected row index when there's no selection.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes more sense as to why I am getting such a large number.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find a work around to get this to work. My original code did not have a check in CPTScatterPlotFieldY to see if `index < [self.values count]`.

```
switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
        if (index < [self.values count]) {
            return [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
        }
        break;

    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:

        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"gpPractices"] && index < [self.values count]) {
            return self.values[index];
        }
        break;
}
return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
```

By adding this check it only tries to access the self.values array if the index is less than the number of objects in the array.